# LWJGLException when starting Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft crashes when I start it up! What do i do? I tried uninstalling it and re-installing it and it doesn't work!

```
Time: 1/15/17 10:54 AM 
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_111, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 77484264 bytes (73 MB) / 150876160 bytes (143 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.11.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated` error will be displayed when there are issues with your graphics drivers.

- Make sure your game is using the correct graphics card. It might be trying to use the Intel graphics on your motherboard instead of an actual powerful graphics card by (for example) nVidea or AMD. This is usually resolved through the settings of the helper program in the system tray.
- Your graphics drivers are outdated, or do not support the required OpenGL version. Go to the website of the manufacturer of your graphics, and install the latest graphics drivers.